# Spree does not showing products on store page for a cloned repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I start learning Spree E-commerce rails application. I followed the steps from http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html and successfully installed the spree on my machine. Then I created a github repository and deployed the code over github. But when I cloned the application from github on other machine I am not able to see the products on spree store page. when i visit the http://localhost:3000 it just displays "No products found". I have already run migrations.

Every help is appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to run seed Run this 
bundle exec rake db:seed & rake spree_sample:load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```

Because images and database data is not there in repo, you have only schema over there